# Dockerfile: COPY folder inside folder

Tags: docker, copy, dockerfile

I want to copy my `/folder` inside `/usr/share/nginx/html/`

So in my dockerfile:

```
COPY folder /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

But this is copying the content of my `folder` inside `/usr/share/nginx/html`

How can I just copy the whole folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to define your foldername inside the directory

```
COPY folder /usr/share/nginx/html/folder
```

or

```
ADD folder /usr/share/nginx/html/folder
```